# jquery DataTables, error with trying to make every column visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

`var words_data` is used for my DataTable, and constantly referenced throughout the file.

I need to make every column visible in words_data. So I tried to use the `columns().every(...)` methods but the following code...

```
       words_table.columns().every( function() {
       $(this).visible(true);
    });
```

gives an error of `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).visible is not a function`

A little confused on how at this point, unless $(this) doesn't actually iterate over each column.

Comment: `.visible()` really isn't a jQuery method. Maybe you look for `.show()` ? And I think [`.every()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp) isn't used correctly here... You probably need `.each()`. --- Posting more code would help us help you...

Comment: .visible() is a DataTables jquery method. Documentation is here https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible() and an example is here https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
   this.visible(true);
```

instead of

```
   $(this).visible(true);
```

refer : https://jsfiddle.net/LxLvL20j/16/

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the column as a parameter to function:

```
words_table.columns().every( function(column) {
   column.visible(true);
});
```

Comment: I got a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined` 
So I take it that I didn't actually grab an instance of DataTables column API.